# TypeError: Cannot read property 'n' of undefined\n at result.toArray

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, node-mongodb-native, mongodb4.0

I'm upgrading from `mongodb 3.6` to `mongodb 4.0` and have problem with aggregates *(it seems)*.

I've got this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'n' of undefined\n    at
>   result.toArray
>   (/eliot-local-git/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/collection_ops.js:237:46)\n
>   at result
>   (/eliot-local-git/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:414:17)\n    at
>   executeCallback
>   (/eliot-local-git/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:406:9)\n    at
>   handleCallback
>   (/eliot-local-git/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:128:55)\n    at
>   cursor.close
>   (/eliot-local-git/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/cursor_ops.js:218:62)\n    at handleCallback
>   (/eliot-local-git/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:128:55)\n    at
>   completeClose
>   (/eliot-local-git/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:887:14)\n    at
>   _endSession (/eliot-local-git/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:898:37)\n    at
>   AggregationCursor.Cursor._endSession
>   (/eliot-local-git/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:193:5)\n
>   at AggregationCursor.Cursor._endSession
>   (/eliot-local-git/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:226:59)\n    at
>   AggregationCursor.Cursor.close
>   (/eliot-local-git/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:898:19)\n    at
>   cursor._next
>   (/eliot-local-git/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/cursor_ops.js:218:23)\n    at handleCallback
>   (/eliot-local-git/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:202:5)\n
>   at _setCursorNotifiedImpl
>   (/eliot-local-git/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:560:38)\n
>   at self._endSession
>   (/eliot-local-git/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:568:46)\n
>   at AggregationCursor.Cursor._endSession
>   (/eliot-local-git/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:193:5)

---

My aggregate call look like :

```
collectionSchema.aggregate(query).exec();
```

---

Using :

mongodb v4.0.0

[image]

---

I've tried to use cursor aswell but it ain't worked:

```
collectionSchema.aggregate(query)
        .cursor({
          batchSize: 10
        })
        .exec();
```

---

@Alex Blex [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/History.md#500--2018-01-17) is where I saw the compatibility to `mongodb-native-driver 3.1`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1543, fixed in v3.1.1 14 hrs ago: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/commit/09c7d8e4ce302f1c8f6339dd19ee4b86e40b30a8

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. As a fix, i'm just letting `count` for now instead of `countDocument` and keep the `deprecation warning`